# How to understand pg-bouncer is working properly with postgres?

Tags: postgresql, pgbouncer

I have already configured one of our server with pg-bouncer.pg-bouncer is listening to 6432 port and postgres is listening to 5432 port. Using like below command I can access pg-bouncer which is giving proxy to postgres 5432 port.

```
psql -p 6432 -U user db1
```

But my question is, how to understand pg-bouncer is working properly with postgres? I mean, when there will be any database request may be read/write will pg-bouncer work automatically now?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you launched pgbouncer with config.ini like below.

```
 [databases]
 template1 = host=localhost port=5432 dbname=template1

 [pgbouncer]
 listen_port = 6432
 listen_addr = localhost
 auth_type = md5
 auth_file = userlist.txt
 logfile = pgbouncer.log
 pidfile = pgbouncer.pid
 admin_users = someuser
```

You can connect to pgbouncer instead of directly to the PostgreSQL server:

```
 $ psql -p 6432 -U someuser template1
```

You application can connect to pgbouncer port 6432 instead of PostgresSQL port 5432, e.g. for java application

```
jdbc:postgresql://server-name:6432/database-name
```